Deployment key issue - error in libcrypto
Preface: I am a very new dev, so many things are still new to me, excuse for my limited knowledge!
I'm adding a small deployment for a site I'm working on, specifically to grab what I push to our private github repo to pull it onto our private repo on a digitalocean server. This is just meant to faciliate my job.
Tutorial I've been following is this one https://gist.github.com/itinerare/e869c2524ddf3dccf5cf4bca3047d825
However I'm stuck at an error with the deploykey that allows the server to read the github repo, it gives the following lines:
Load key "/home/runner/.ssh/id_ed25519": error in libcrypto
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
***@***: Permission denied (publickey, password).

I've tried adding newlines, changing the key, copy-pasting the key again, it still errors out. My best guess was that it's a Windows shenanigan again (I run Win10) as the tutorial's author said they didn't have issues doing that on Linux.
For what it's worth, I didn't had to generate a key to connect to the site as I already had one I use so I reused it, which I doubt would cause any troubles.
What I did in short:

Open the existing key to connect to the server in puttygen to copy the openssh string and paste it in the SSH_KEY github secret.
Generate the deploy key as asked in the tutorial for private repo, did cat, and copypasted the results in the github deploy key section.

